# What is '##' in C?

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I'm using USART in Keil and I saw this;

```
#define USART_DRV_NUM 6

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600

#define _USART_Driver_(n) Driver_USART##n
#define USART_Driver_(n) _USART_Driver_(n)

extern ARM_DRIVER_USART USART_Driver_(USART_DRV_NUM);
#define ptrUSART (&USART_Driver_(USART_DRV_NUM))
```

Here is the thing;

```
#define _USART_Driver_(n) Driver_USART##n
```

I couldn't find any examples on the Internet. Does anyone know something about this thing?

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Token Pasting Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation). It generates an identifier for example

```
#define _USART_Driver_(n) Driver_USART##n

int _USART_Driver_(_EXAMPLE);
```

is translated to

```
int Driver_USART_EXAMPLE;
```

Note that, `n` is not a variable. It's replaced literally before actual compilation in the prepropcessing stage.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I use this in a loop? For example;

while(i--){
  husart.instance = _USART_Driver_(i)
}

Comment: No, you can't. It's replaced at compile time, `n` cannot be a variable.

Comment: Is there anything like that I can use in a loop?

Comment: Yes an array. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont want to use array. This token pasting operator seems very clean. An array takes more memory than this macro.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This may not be the right option for you.

Comment: I have an input. For example : "init -usart 6" and I need to init USART6 :)

Comment: Can I use enum for this macro?

Comment: No, macros are compile time and you need a runtime solution, it will not work with macros at all.

Comment: So, I need to use an array? Is that most efficent method?

Comment: Perhaps, I can't tell you without seeing the ACTUAL problem. You can send it to me at iharob@gmail.com and I can take a look. BTW: انا اسمي يعرب